# PyTest shows a wrong answer

Tags: python, pytest

Can you guys tell me what am I doing wrong with my unit testing?

```
class Blizzard(Storm):
    def __init__(self, name, wind_speed, temp):
        self.temp = temp
        super().__init__(name, wind_speed)

    def calculate_classification(self) -> str:
        if self.wind_speed >= 35:
            return "Blizzard"
        elif self.wind_speed >= 45 and self.temp <= -12:
            return "Severe Blizzard"
        return "Snow Storm"
```

Here is my class to check what kind of blizzard is there and below you can see my unit test code:

```
def test_severe_blizzard():
    b1 = Blizzard("Wendy", 46, -12)
    assert b1.calculate_classification() == 'Severe Blizzard'
```

[Here is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxU0L.png)

Comment: `if self.wind_speed >= 35:` - it matches, so your `elif` never triggers. You should swap their order so that more specific tests come first.

Comment: Test your code manually before you automate the test.  This has nothing to do with `pytest` -- the function is faulty.

Comment: So your test tells you that your code is incorrect. Add print statements or otherwise debug your code to find out why.

Comment: @Prune I disagree with this approach. The point of an automated test is so you don't have to manually test. In this case, the automated test can be used to debug the faulty logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wind speed is greater than 35 so it returns the first if statement.

Comment: damn, that was so silly, thank you very much :D

Comment: @Kapol Silliness can be avoided using a debugger! [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953)